# Redirect to custom login page when openam cdsso enabled

Tags: openam, forgerock

I have AM 6.0.0 (docker image - `docker pull gcr.io/forgerock-io/openam:6.0.0`) with a web agent and CDSSO enabled. I want to redirect to the custom login page. I have enabled custom login configuration and added a conditional URL but it always redirects to XUI (default login page).

Following are my custom property config:
[image: conditional login url]

App sends a request to `openam/cdservlet` then this one redirects to default login instead of the custom login page, I have tried to add just port or base hostname in conditional part but the same result.
[image: openam requests]

Comment: it's seems you are using old agents, since version 5.0 Agents do not use CDCServlet anymore , but use OIDC. `custom.login` is only for newer agents.

Comment: Aha, yeah. I have to redirect to the login page directly with a goto param which will be used to redirect back after successful login.

Comment: You don't have to, Agents before version 5 redirect to CDCServlet URL and will automatically append `goto` based on the incoming HTTP request. If User is not authenticated yet, CDCServlet will forward to authentication

Comment: Nope, CDCservlet is not forwarding to the custom login page, configured in conditional login properties. SDK or app has to get those conditional properties via API call and then redirect directly there and append `goto` for a final destination after login.

Comment: As I said you are mixing up things. CustomLogin URL is a Agent 5 thing, not Agent 4. Agent 5 do not use CDCServlet but use OIDC implicit grant flow.

Comment: oh sorry. yeah, I am using AM 6.0+ which has agent 5. so I had to redirect to login from SDK after getting this custom conditional via API.

Comment: If you are using Agent 5, then the HTTP trace provided is not the real one. You may edit the question accordingly. AM acting as OIDC provider has to be able to see the SSO token generated by the custom URL, otherwise it can not issue the ID Token when OIDC implicit flow is triggered by the agent.